# How to calculate the total values of array items

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I'm trying to get the total amount of calculating part number four of each item, but array_sum is not working with my code, and when I echo $parts i get only one number which is 4 .. here's my code:

```
$test = "2021/05/10,0,0,0,1|2021/05/11,0,0,0,2|2021/05/0,0,0,0,3|2021/05/13,0,0,0,4";
$test = explode("|", $test);

foreach($test as $key => $value){
    $parts = explode(",", $test[$key])[4];
}

echo array_sum($parts);
```

Comment: Of course `array_sum` doesn't work, `$parts` is not an array. Did you mean to do `$parts[] = ...`?

Comment: Also, if the only purpose is to add them up, do it in the `foreach()` loop - no need for an array.

Comment: But it became an array after foreach

Comment: No, it is string `4` after the foreach.  Look at the code at @El_Vanja

Comment: @Nigel Ren do you mean i should write another `foreach` and and use `array_sum` inside it? can you please explain your comment ? thanks

Comment: You set `$sum = 0;` and then in the loop `$sum += explode(",", $test[$key])[4];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `$parts` is a string and overwritten each iteration, so append it to an array:

```
$parts[] = explode(",", $test[$key])[4];
```

But for fun:

```
preg_match_all('/,(\d+)(\||$)/', $test, $matches);
echo array_sum($matches[1]);
```

- match a `,` and then match and capture in group 1 `()` any number of digits `\d+` that is followed by `|` or the end of string `$`

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map(callback, array)` on `dates` *array*, Which is exploded by `|`. and explode it again by `,` getting only for each `date` the last part which is at position *4*.

```php
$dates = "2021/05/10,0,0,0,1|2021/05/11,0,0,0,2|
         2021/05/0,0,0,0,3|2021/05/13,0,0,0,4";

$parts = array_map(fn($part)=>explode(",", $part)[4], explode("|", $dates));
```

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($parts);
```

**Prints*:*

```
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
*/
```

And for sum of these parts:

```php
echo array_sum($parts); //10
```